# Ruby on Rails + Backbone.js Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, routes

I'm trying to integrate backbone.js as the frontend framework for my rails app. I have a lists model (among others) in rails.

When setting up my backbone frontend, I'm using history pushState as opposed to hashtags. I want backbone/js to handle a lot of the front end (users logged in affects the header, etc.) and have the app have the 'app like feel'.

However, when accessing /lists it forwards to the rails controller, and not backbone. Is there a solution around this so I can use the built in sessions with rails and backbone, when the urls for rails and the front end have the same name?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are talking about, since your Rails application should just be providing your client application with a REST api. Could you post an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anybody looking for an answer: the solution we used was just let Backbone control everything except login/register forms using API calls our iOS app also uses